# meteor.js iron-router: prevent static template re-render and glitching?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, iron-router

I have a global template:

```
<template name="layout">
{{> header}}
{{> primaryNav}}
{{yield 'banner'}}
{{yield}}
{{> footer}}
{{> deleteConfirmModal }}
<span class="responsive-state"></span>
</template>
```

and when I do a route

```
@route 'blog',
    path: '/blog/'
```

Everything works dandy. I can click back and forth through my header links and nav links with no glitching. But if I add a data context:

```
@route 'blog',
    path: '/blog/'
    data: ->
        blogPosts: BlogPosts.find({}, {date: -1, time: -1})
```

When providing a data context, whenever I navigate to and away from a route in which a data context is provided all the templates nested in the layout template appear to re-render, causing glitches due to style classes that get wiped and then replaced. If I route to any other paths that do not require (and are not provided) a data context, the static templates do not re-render.

Is there a way to prevent certain static templates from re-rendering when providing a data context for a specific route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Meteor in the current state- you should probably rely on renders breaking most stuff.

As for iron-router - the `data` is stored in a `ReactiveVar`, and it ensures that any changes to `data` cause the `layoutTemplate` to re-render (this might be an over-simplified interpretation).

You might be able to:

- Remove styles that animate on addition
- Try using preserve to keep the elements in-tact. (note: that it does not preserve anything but the element reference, all values/attributes get reset as per template generated element)
- Wait for meteor 1.0, or use one of the new template rendering previews which "patch" the DOM instead of re-inserting every element on render.

Comment: Is there any explicit way to render a template or templates outside of the layout template and still use iron-router for the dynamic stuff?

Comment: "calling" a template renders it- eg. `var html = Templates.blog({someData: true})` (http://docs.meteor.com/#template_call).

Comment: You could also try using the `{{#constant}}` helper to prevent re-renders