# Router only render certain templates

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a layout with 2 containers 1)productView and 2)calendarView. My Router is configured as follows:

```
this.route('productDetail', {
    layout: 'main',
    path: '/products/:_id',
    waitnOn: function(){...},
    data: function(){...},
    yieldTemplates: {
        'calendarView: { to: calendar }
    }
});
```

I now want to achieve that whenever the route changes (e.g. from 'products/1' to 'products/2') only the productView is re-rendered and that calendarView does nothing. As for now every time the 'productDetail/:id' route is called the 'calendarView' function 'Template.calendarView.rendered' gets called and re-renders the template. My 'main' template looks like this:

```
<template name="main">
    <div>
        {{yield}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{yield 'calendar'}}
    </div>
</template>
```

[image: layout schema]

Is there a way to tell the router to only render certain templates? Or is there a better solution?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958299/meteor-js-iron-router-prevent-static-template-re-render-and-glitching?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you use the router for the calendar view ?
I think one solution may be not to use the router for the calendar view

```
<template name="main">
    <div>
        {{yield}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{>calendar}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, but the problem remains. It still re-renders both templates...

Comment: Did you check that none of the session variables that your calendar template read are set by the code involved by your product template rerendering ?

Comment: Another good point. But I meanwhile work with a very simple test-setup with no dependencies and no Session variables and experience the same behaviour.